# How do you generate a paid invoice PDF for a Stripe checkout session?

Tags: stripe-payments

My web app currently emails customers their Stripe receipt after purchase via stripe checkout. However for some customers this isn't enough – they want a paid invoice for the purchase with the information of my business and their business on it. How do you generate a PDF with this info?

I've investigated Stripe Invoices, but that seems to be a system for collecting payment. I already have payment from the checkout sessions. I just want to send the customer a souped-up receipt, really.

I've also considered using some js PDF library to generate the PDF myself, but it felt like there must be an easy way to do what I want with the Stripe API.

Comment: The email containing the receipt sent following payment should also include a link to download an invoice PDF.

Comment: @JonathanSteele unfortunately stripe checkout receipts don't seem to have that. https://b.stripecdn.com/docs-statics-srv/assets/terminal-pre-built-receipt.7879fcc1c9eaea36e3af4dabada4f82b.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ~November 2022 there is a feature just for this:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/post-payment-invoices

It lets you generate an invoice just by setting a parameter in the request for creating Checkout Session.

Comment: The feature is out of beta now, you can find it here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/post-payment-invoices

Comment: @Happy Cool! Consider posting that as an answer. I think it should be the accepted solution to the op's question. .)

Comment: I did but sadly the mods deleted it because apparently its a duplicated answer and I should have picked from the existing answers .. meh. fyi @chrisf

Comment: @Happy Jeez, these mods. I'll edit my answer at least. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I've asked Stripe support the same thing.

They said creating invoices with Stripe Checkout is a common feature request but it sounds like it won't be coming for many months.

The only workaround for now is to use invoicing instead of Checkout:

https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration

And for a similar UI to Checkout, use this:
https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/hosted-invoice-page

Answer (score 1):

When creating a Checkout session, set the invoice_creation[enabled] parameter to true.
After the payment completes, Stripe will automatically send an invoice summary to the email address provided by the customer during checkout. The invoice summary will include links to download the invoice PDF and receipt for the invoice.